# AWS CloudFormation: Writing a Lambda function to verify domain ownership for ACM Certificates

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, automation, aws-lambda, aws-certificate-manager

I am creating an `ACM Cert` in CloudFormation.  Based on this [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-validate.html), AWS sends out an email to the addresses registered in WHOIS.

The docs for CloudFormation say:

> **Important**
>
> When you use the AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate
>   resource in an AWS CloudFormation stack, the stack will remain in the
>   CREATE_IN_PROGRESS state and any further stack operations will be
>   delayed until you act upon the instructions in the certificate
>   validation email.

Usually for similar things, like creating and accepting a `VPC peering connection in multiple accounts`, or enabling `SNS Topic subscriptions` that are created in CFN, I write a lambda function as a **Custom Resource** to handle that.

What would be the API calls needed to verify domain ownership?  Can this even be done in a Lambda function?

Chances are the emails will go to the IT Manager, but it would be nice to have that automated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API call to verify domain ownership as this need to verified with Email on your whois records.

You can also automate it this way. Change the technical contact email address of whois records to an ses domain email address.

SES Email --> S3 Bucket (Trigger) --> Lambda (Confirm with the link in the content of email).

You need to revert your email address back to your inbox, incase of any email need to be delivered for Technical contact relating to your domain or subdomain.

**Documentation on domain verification:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-validate.html

Thx !

Comment: The link in the email returns a form and iirc there's a CSRF token, so it will be a little trickier than described.  Also, the body must be parsed to ensure that the request contains your AWS account number, otherwise you create a huge security hole where any other account can create certs for your domains... with help from your own automation.

Comment: This kind of things should not be automated unless there is a huge volume to process. Most of the business need for this is a one off, except services like slack or anything related to custom domains.

Answer (score 1):

This repo [aws-cfn-acm](https://github.com/alexzhangs/aws-cfn-acm) contains a CloudFormation template including a Lambda function that works in a similar way to your requirements.

The Lambda function automates the certificate validation by the `DNS` method, not the `EMAIL` method you are using. It requires the domain name related to the certificate must be hosted in `name.com`. name.com provides an API service that the Lambda functions can leverage on. It should be easy to extend to support other DNS service providers.

The template is using the inline Lambda function, the code is not easy to read, here's a [well-formatted version](https://github.com/alexzhangs/aws-cfn-acm/blob/main/inline-lambda-origin/LambdaValidateAcmDomain.py) of the Lambda function.